# Why does Grid clip when not given enough space?

Tags: xaml, layout, uwp

Consider the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid
        Grid.Row="1"
        Height="100">
        <Rectangle
            Fill="Red" />

        <Rectangle
            Fill="Yellow"
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Margin="0,-100,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This works just fine, half of the yellow Rectangle is shown above the red (i.e. superimposing any content in the upper row). Now if I change the height of the RowDefinition to 99 instead of 100, so that the inner Grid doesn't get the space it is asking for, the yellow Rectangle is clipped. Does anyone know why this is and is there any workaround? I know that ideally there shouldn't be a height defined for the inner Grid but that is out of my hands...

Comment: Found a workaround; setting the row height to Auto and providing a negative bottom margin to the inner Grid. Still no clue about the clipping though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what happens behind the scenes, but I suspect that when grid's space is calculated and its height is bigger than available, then it's being clipped - every element is being checked if it fits to the row. This may be ommited once height is lower than available - thus negative margin may work. At least it's how I'm thinking of this. If you want more precise information you may try to dig [at reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Grid.cs,1e9619f2e823c6c4).

However, if you want your grid to follow the row's height - I would suggest to use *VerticalAlignment*:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="0,-100,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Personally I don't like fixed margins for element positioning and there is probably a better way to arrange your elements, though it depends on your needs.